# How to Navigate and Scroll to an Element with ID in a Next.js Page wrapped with AnimatePresence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, next.js, framer-motion

I am using [Framer Motion](https://github.com/framer/motion) to animate [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) page transitions. However using the using [AnimatePresence](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/) breaks the `hash` link navigation and the page no longer goes to the targeted `id` element.

The page transitions are perfect until you want to navigate to a harsh ID on the page :(

```
// I have a link component setup like this
// index.tsx
<Link href="/about#the-team" scroll={false}>
  <a>The Team</a>
</Link>

// Targeting another page `about.tsx` with the id
// about.tsx

{/* ...many sections before.. */}
<section id="the-team">{content}</section>
```

I have a custom `_app.tsx` as shown below.

```
// _app.tsx
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps): JSX.Element => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      <Component {...pageProps} key={router.route} />
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

I am expecting to go directly to the section with `id="the-team"` but it won't work. A refresh of the page with the hash link shows that it's originally at the target element but quickly jumps to the top. It's so fast and easy to miss. How do I retain the page transitions but still be able to navigate to hash id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Culprit is the [`exitBeforeEnter`](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#animatepresenceprops.exitbeforeenter)
prop on on `AnimatePresence`. Removing the prop fixes the hash id navigation but breaks some of my use-case.

> If set to true, `AnimatePresence` will only render one component at a time. The exiting component will finish its exit animation before the entering component is rendered.
>   - ***framer-motion docs***

I couldn't just remove the `exitBeforeEnter` prop as I had included it to fix a bug I had where targeting a node in the entering page collided with the identical one in the old instance of the exiting page. For example a `ref` logic on an animated svg header in the exiting Page colliding with the entering page's header svg ref logic.

To get the best of both worlds, Using the [`onExitComplete`](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#animatepresenceprops.onexitcomplete)
that "Fires when all exiting nodes have completed animating out", I passed it a callback that checks for the hash from the `widow.location.hash` and smooth scrolls to the id using [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)
Note: `onExitComplete` is only effective if `exitBeforeEnter` prop is `true`.

```
// pages/_app.tsx
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';

// The handler to smoothly scroll the element into view
const handExitComplete = (): void => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // Get the hash from the url
    const hashId = window.location.hash;

    if (hashId) {
      // Use the hash to find the first element with that id
      const element = document.querySelector(hashId);

      if (element) {
        // Smooth scroll to that elment
        element.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth',
          block: 'start',
          inline: 'nearest',
        });
      }
    }
  }
};

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps): JSX.Element => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter onExitComplete={handExitComplete}>
      <Component {...pageProps} key={router.route} />
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

---

Live [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/answert-nextjs-framer-motion-scroll-to-id-bkd3d).

**PS**: For some reason the the `window.location.hash` in the sandbox preview is always an empty string, breaking the hash navigation but opening the preview [in a separate browser tab](https://bkd3d.sse.codesandbox.io/) works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, had the exact problem on an infinite scroll catalog (stored in a Context); this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad it was helpful

Comment: Great!,  a question and how to I add it to the same page, did not work for me. https://codesandbox.io/s/answert-nextjs-framer-motion-scroll-to-id-forked-450s3?file=/pages/index.tsx

Comment: Thank you for this! I added a short delay before it scrolls into the element since I have enter/exit animations. :)